# Translation complicated curl command to python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, curl

I am making a program and I have to translate a Curl command to python, I know how to do requests but not a complicated Curl command like this one so I have no idea how to do it. Can someone help me?

Curl command:

```
curl -H "public-api-token: 59d46c97de11677e7b23750da01ff6a5" -X PUT -d "urlToShorten=google.com" https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url
```

It would be much appreciated if someone wants to translate it for me and wants to explain to me how to do it.

Comment: _It would be much appreciated if someone wants to translate it for me and wants to explain to me how to do it._ Stack Overflow is not a free code writing/software development service. Have you tried anything, done any research? Looking at the command, and the answers, this seems trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `requests` module in python:

```
import requests

r = requests.put('https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url', data = {'urlToShorten':'google.com'}, headers={'public-api-token' : '59d46c97de11677e7b23750da01ff6a5'})

status_code=r.status_code # get status code
res=r.json() # get response as json
```

Explaining the code:
1) `url` is https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url
2) you need to pass a Public API token in the headers so you will provide the `headers` arg as a dict (see above).
3) finally, the payload is specified in the `data` arg as shown in the above example.

`requests` module is quite useful, you may check out the docs here:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
my_url = "https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url"
my_data = {"urlToShorten": "google.com"}
my_headers = {"public-api-token":"59d46c97de11677e7b23750da01ff6a5"}
response = requests.put(my_url, my_data, headers=my_headers)
print(reponse.json())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm sure this would have worked too